# Cummean column-wise and ignoring NAs

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, mean, na

I have a data frame looking like this:

```
as.data.frame(matrix(c(1,2,3,NA,4,5,NA,NA,9), nrow = 3, ncol = 3))
  V1 V2 V3
1  1 NA NA
2  2  4 NA
3  3  5  9
```

I would like to calculate a cumulative mean per column, which ignores NAs, so something like this:

```
  V1 V2 V3
1  1 NA NA
2  3  4 NA
3  6  9  9
```

I tried this:

```
B[!is.na(A)] <- as.data.frame(apply(B[!is.na(A)], 2, cummean))
```

But received this error message:

> dim(X) must have a positive length

Thanks for your help!

Cheers

Comment: what is `cummean()`? It is not in base R. Please make your example reproducable, i.e. edit your question: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44177721/edit

Comment: it is in dplyr package

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
A <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(1,2,3,NA,4,5,NA,NA,9), nrow = 3, ncol = 3))
B <- as.data.frame(apply(A,2,function(col){ 
                                col[!is.na(col)] <- dplyr::cummean(col[!is.na(col)])
                                return(col) 
                             }))

> B
   V1  V2 V3
1 1.0  NA NA
2 1.5 4.0 NA
3 2.0 4.5  9
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
setDT(d1)
for(j in seq_along(d1)){
  set(d1, i = which(!is.na(d1[[j]])), j=j, value = cummean(d1[[j]][!is.na(d1[[j]])]))
}

d1
#    V1  V2 V3
#1: 1.0  NA NA
#2: 1.5 4.0 NA
#3: 2.0 4.5  9
```